# css reverse a blur fade-out effect

Tags: css

I am using a CSS3 blur fade-out effect and I would like to reverse the effect when the image is shown again. I'm trying to create is to fade in with blur and go to sharp, although I can't seem to reverse the effect  in my class `.home-holder.in`.

**CSS:**

```
.home-holder.out{
    -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.4, 1.4);
    opacity: 0.25;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.home-holder.in{
    -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.4, 1.4);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in;
    transition: all 0.25s ease-in;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: You are using the same `filter` in both states so it wouldn't become sharp, right? Have I misunderstood your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe change the .in class's blur to 0px?

```
.home-holder.in {
    -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.4, 1.4);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in;
    transition: all 0.25s ease-in;
    visibility: visible;
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OXNMvj

Comment: thank you, I have removed the `-webkit-transform: scale(1.4, 1.4);` as the image size is enlarged.